# Johnson-Cut Max-Cut Approximation

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, graph-theory, computer-science

The Johnson-Cut is an $O(n^2)$ [Max-Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_cut) approximation with a factor of 2. I have these definitions for MC and none for JC so I assume they're the same:

> $G = (V,E,w)$ with $|V| = n$ and $w : E \rightarrow Q^+$
>
> Maximize $w(V_1,V_2) = \sum_ {v_1 \in V_1,  v_2 \in V_2} w(v_1,v_2)$

The algorithm is

```
JohnsonCut(G = (V,E,w))
    V1,V2 := ∅;
    for v ∈ V do
        if w(v,V1) > w(v,V2) do
            V2 := V2 ∪ {v}
        else
            V1 := V1 ∪ {v}
        fi
    od
    return (V1,V2)
```

My intuition tells me this means that $MC/2 \leq JC \leq MC$ (rather than $JC \leq 2MC$) but the proof eludes me. It is evident that the algorithm isn't performing anywhere near enough comparisons for optimality but why is it performing enough to guarantee a factor of 2?

Comment: You'd better explain what $w$ is. I thought at first that $w(u,v)$ would be the capacity of the edge between $u$ and $v$, but no, its first argument is a vertex and its second argument is a set of vertices, so that's not it. Is $w(v, S)$ the sum of the capacities of all the edges $(u,v)$ for $u\in S$?

Comment: There; and that is how I understand it, though I'm not really much of an authority on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if $w(v,V_x) = \sum_ {v \notin V_1 \cup V_2,  v_x \in V_x} w(v,v_x)$ we can look at what the cut for each iteration will yield.

The first vertex we look at will of course be added to $V_1$, both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are empty sets, so $w(v,V_x)$ will return 0 in both calls.

Note that we only look at each edge once (if an edge goes to neither set, we don't bother with it *yet*). This is the key to it all.

$v$ is the vertex we are examining in the current iteration.
Name the sum of the weight of all edges of $v$ that go to $V_1$ $w_{v_1}$ and all that go to $V_2$ $w_{v_2}$. $z$ is the cut we are going to choose and $w_z$ its weight.

Clearly $w_z \geq (w_{v_1} + w_{v_2})/2$ (hint: set $z=v_1$, times 2 minus $w_{v_1}$).

The sum of all our cuts would then be:
$\sum{w_z} \geq \frac{\sum{w_{v_1}+ w_{v_2}}}{2}$

The sum of the weight of all the edges in the graph is $W$. The Max-Cut result can of course not be greater than that.
Because we are only looking at each edge exactly once we know that $W=\sum{w_{v_1} + w_{v_2}}$.
Ergo $\sum{w_z} \geq \frac{W}{2}$

The running time should be $O(n^2)$. We look at $n$ vertices, but each of them can have edges to $n - 1$ other vertices.